# Swipe effect on button in android like iphone?

Tags: android

I am new to android. And i am creating an app in which i want to apply a swipe effect on button like iPhone button. When button pressed anything will not occurred. But once it swipe on button something should done. My question is .....is it possible to apply on Swipe effect on android button like iphone? Please give some idea to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: do nothing on onClick and do something on onTouch

Comment: i ddnt mean onTouch i meant onSwipe on button. Like when we use gesture whole screen can swipe left-to-right and right-to-left but we can we do it for button only not whole screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/793607)  has some nice information on "flinging" which is the android term you may be looking for.  You need to apply a listener like this to whatever you want to "swipe" on.

Here is some of the pertinent code from Mirek Rusin's answer:

```
 private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It maybe very late but I have created a small library for this very purpose. It allows you to swipe and customise the behaviour of your button from xml. [Slide Button](https://github.com/masterlittle/SlideButton)

Basically it involves overriding of the onTouch() event and making changes according to the coordinates that are received.  Its a simple thing after that to set the background as you want

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is may be **[Swipe-To-Dismiss](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/swipe-to-dismiss/).**

**[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/2980593)** project.

This has **swipe** functionality on **views**. Try and modify as per your requirement.

[image]